# How can i avoid using the same element in my two sum solution

Tags: ruby, hash

So I am trying to get a solution to my two sum problem and I am stuck, I need to print the indices for the elements which add up to the target and my solution will return an element twice if it is one half of the target

```
def two_sum(nums, target)
  num_hash = Hash.new(0)
  nums.each_with_index do |num,idx|
    num_hash[num] = idx

    if num_hash.key?(target - num) && target % num != 0
      return [num_hash[num], idx]
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

So I don't think the problem is related to the number being 1/2 of the target, it just seems to be "if a solution is found, it returns the same index twice". For instance, using the sample set `[2, 7, 11, 15]`

```
two_sum([2, 7, 11, 15], 14) # => [2, 7, 11, 15]
```

So, `7` is half of `14`, which is the target, and instead of returning the index `1` twice, as you suggest it would, it returns the original input array (the result of `nums.each_with_index`. However, if we try passing a target of `9`, it behaves as you describe:

```
two_sum([2, 7, 11, 15], 9) # => [1, 1]
```

The reason for this, is because of the line:

```
return [num_hash[num], idx]
```

you have already set `num` into the `num_hash` (`num_hash[num] = idx`) and then you are returning both the `idx` and `num_hash[num]`, which is also `idx`. So what you want to do is:

```
return [num_hash[target - num], idx]
```

and then to 'fix' all the elements being returned when no result is found, just return `[]` at the end of the method:

```
def two_sum(nums, target)
  num_hash = Hash.new(0)
  nums.each_with_index do |num,idx|
    num_hash[num] = idx

    if num_hash.key?(target - num) && target % num != 0
      return [num_hash[target - num], idx]
    end
  end

  []
end
```

and now:

```
two_sum([2, 7, 11, 15], 14) # => []
two_sum([2, 7, 11, 15], 9) # => [0, 1]
```

Note: you also have a problem with the code where, if you have the same number twice, it doesn't find the answer:

```
two_sum([2, 7, 11, 7, 15], 14) # => []
```

left for you to figure out, just wanted to point this out to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method [Array#combination](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-combination) to advantage here.

```
def two_sum(nums, target)
  nums.each_index.to_a.combination(2).select { |i,j| nums[i] + nums[j] == target }
end

two_sum([2, 7, 11, 15], 14)
  #=> []
two_sum([2, 7, 11, 15], 9)
  #=> [[0, 1]]
two_sum([2, 4, 7, 5], 9)
  #=> [[0, 2], [1, 3]]
two_sum([2, 2, 2, 2], 4)
  #=> [[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]
two_sum([2, 4, 7, 5], 8)
  #=> []
```

For

```
nums = [2, 4, 7, 5]
target = 9
```

the steps are as follows.

```
a = nums.each_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: [2, 4, 7, 5]:each_index>
```

We can see the elements that will be generated by this enumerator by converting it to an array.

```
b = a.to_a
  #=> [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Next,

```
c = b.combination(2)
  #=> #<Enumerator: [0, 1, 2, 3]:combination(2)>
c.to_a
  #=> [[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]
```

The rest is straightforward as `select` merely selects those pairs of indices  passed to it (`i,j`) whose corresponding values, `num[i]` and `num[j]`, sum to `target`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is ...

```
return [num_hash[target-num], idx]
```

Comment: Thank you guys I've been stuck on this since yesterday